# Pig: How to flatten & re-join bags within bags

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've got an example where we're trying to do what appears to be a simple join:

```
A = load 'data6' as ( item:chararray, d:int, things:bag{(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)})} );
B = load 'data7' as ( v:chararray, r:chararray );

    grunt> cat data1
    'item1' 111     { ('thing1', 222, {('value1'),('value2')}) }
    grunt> cat data2
    'value1'        'result1'
    'value2'        'result2'
```

We want to join the `'result1'`, `'result2'` data of `data2` into the entry in `data1`, on the obvious `value` field.

We managed to flatten it:

```
A = load 'data6' as ( item:chararray, d:int, things:bag{(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)})} );
B = load 'data7' as ( v:chararray, r:chararray );
F1 = foreach A generate item, d, flatten(things);
F2 = foreach F1 generate item..d1, flatten(values);
```

Then we joined the 2nd dataset in:

```
J = join F2 by v, B by v
J1 = foreach J generate item as item, d as d, thing as thing, d1 as d1, F2::things::values::v as v, r as r;         --Remove duplicate field & clean up naming

    dump J1
    ('item1',111,'thing1',222,'value1','result1')
    ('item1',111,'thing1',222,'value2','result2')
```

Now we need to call a UDF function once for each item, so we need to re-group those 2 levels of bags. Each item has 0 or more things, and each thing has 0 or more values, and the values now may or may not have a result.

How do we get back to:

```
 ('item1', 111, { 'thing1', 222, { ('value1, 'result1'), ('value2', 'result2') }
```

All of my attempts at grouping and re-joining have exploded in complexity, failed to produce the correct result, and run in 4+ mapreduce jobs what should be 1 mapreduce job in Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may work, R2 is the final result:

```
group_by_item_d_thing_d1 = group J1 by item, d, thing, d1;
R1 = foreach group_by_item_d_thing_d1 generate group.item, group.d, group.thing, group.d1, J1;
group_by_item_d = group R1 by item, d;
R2 = foreach group_by_item_d generate group.item, group.d, R1;
```